# Trying to create a list by grouping child elements with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public class City
{
    public string cityName { get; set; }
    public string stateName { get; set; }
    public int population { get; set; }

    public List<Interstate> Interstates { get; set; }
}

public class Interstate
{
    public int interstateName { get; set; }

    public string interestateString
    {
        get { return "I-" + interstateName; }
    }

    public City city { get; set; }
}
```

The cities are populated at runtime with all the interestates they have.

What I need to do, and can't seem to find how, is to create a list of distinc interestates so I can show which cities have the same interestates.

I tried selecting and grouping and can't get the desired results.

Comment: "create a list of distinc interestates so I can show which cities have the same interestates". Sorry ! I am confused. What are you trying to do ? If you are trying to get Distinct, did you try the `Distinct()` method ?

Comment: @Shyju I'm trying to create a new List with all the interstates and the cities that have those interestates

Comment: You want a list of interstates or list of cities ?

Comment: A list with interestates, containing all the cities.

Example: I-35 -> New York, California

Comment: Sorry ! i am still confused. Can you share what you have tried and what your expected output is ?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your class design. If I'm reading it right a City class can have multiple Interstates, but each Interstate class can only be associated to one City.  So I-95 in Raleigh is a different instance than I-95 Savannah.  But then it is circular and that City property contains multiple Interstate instances.  I would remove the circular reference and take City out of Interstate unless you truly do need to distinguish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by first selecting all of the interstates into an IEnumerable, and then using Linq's GroupBy extension to get an IGrouping which would contain the interstate property you use for an identifier as the key and all of the cities.  Here is some pseudo-code:

```
// Get all of your cities
List<City> allCities = GetAllCities();

// Get all interstates
IEnumerable<Interstate> allInterstates = allCities.SelectMany(c => c.Interstates);

// Now group your Interstates
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Interstate>> interstateGroups = allInterstates.GroupBy(i => i.interstateName);

// Now you can iterate through your group
foreach(IGrouping<int, Interstate> group in interstateGroups)
{
    // Get all the cities for this particular group which represents all interstates with the same name
    IEnumerable<City> citiesForThisInterstate = group.Select(g => g.Cities);
}
```

A lot of this could be chained into a single LINQ statement, but I wanted to break it out to be verbose and explain each step.

Comment: Using your pseudo-code, I managed to solve the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary mapping `Interstate`s to cities that own a part of that interstate. At first create a distinct list of `Interstate`s:

```
List<City> yourCities = ... // populated as you said
List<Interstate> interStates = yourCities.SelectMany(city => city.Interstates).Distinct();
```

Then create the dictionary by filtering the cities:

```
Dictionary<Interstate, List<City>> interStatesToCities = 
    interStates.ToDictionary(s => s, 
                             s => yourCities.Where(city => city.Interstates.Contains(s)).ToList());
```

Note that you may need a proper equality comparison for the `Interstate` class for `Distinct` and `ToDictionary` to work properly. By default, the `Interstate`s are compared by reference. So if you have different instances representing `I-35` you may need to override `Equals()` or implement an `IEqualityComparer<Interstate>`.